# Avoiding using a "using" clause in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I wrote a UrlHelper and in every view I need to include an using clause:

```
@using MyWebPage.Helpers
```

Is there way to avoid it? That would be great if this import automatically.

I added this in web.config as below:

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
    <add namespace="MyWebPage.Helpers" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

But it wouldn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 web.configs in the project.

1. For Views
2. For application

You need to include the namespace in proper web.config which is for views.
Once you include it in proper namespace you don't have to include it in every page.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host ....>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
    <add namespace="MyWebPage.Helpers" />
  </namespaces>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
</pages>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the namespace into `Views/web.config`, close all cshtml files, reopen them, voila.

Comment: Thanks for the remark to reopen the .cshtml file! Was getting frustrated why the namespace was not working...